# AngularJs: Custom Directive's dynamic template not substituting attribute values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have these line on my view:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="localjhourlad">
```

.....

```
<ng-carousel-item 
   title="AngularJS custom directive's title attribute"
   content="I am a custom attribute, as well!"
   thumbnail="/img/logo.png">
</ng-carousel-item>
```

And on my app.js file:

```
var ngApp = angular.module("localjhourlad", ['ngRoute']);

ngApp
    .config(['$interpolateProvider',
        function ($interpolateProvider) {
            $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
            $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
    }]);

//Custom Directives
ngApp
    .directive('ngCarouselItem', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '<div class="item">' +
                      '<div style="background-image: url([[thumbnail]])">' +
                      '<div class="carousel-caption">' +
                      '<h3>[[title]]</h3>' +
                      '<p class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">[[content]]</p>' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '</div>'
        }
    });
```

Everything works as intended as I am seeing the custom directive element being replaced by the directive's template, only the expression bindings are not being replaced by the attributes values, to wit:

```
<div class="item" 
   title="AngularJS custom directive's title attribute" 
   content="I am a custom attribute, as well!"      
   thumbnail="/img/logo.png">

   <div style="background-image: url()">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
         <h3 class="ng-binding"></h3>
         <p class="hidden-sm hidden-xs ng-binding"></p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm out of ideas right now. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does it work with the standard brackets {{ thumbnail }} ??

Comment: Neither native "{{}}" nor custom "[[]]" work. Exactly same blank results. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not declaring scope in the directive, which means you are using the scope of your parent. But in that scope, `thumbnail/title/content` are not variables on the scope, but rather attributes on your DOM element.

You have 2 options:

Either declare an **isolated scope**, like this:

```
scope: {
      thumbnail: "@",
      title: "@",
      content: "@"
}
```

And then keep your HTML as it is, or:

**Add those to scope** in the **link** function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    scope.thumbnail = attr.thumbnail;
    scope.title = attr.title;
    scope.content = attr.content;
}
```

Comment: See my answer, if you declare the isolated scope then you dont need to access them as attr.template
They will be available on the scope directly.

Comment: @Yash That's why I said 2 options, either/or.

Comment: +Omri, this works! Can you correct the "scope.template = attr.template;" line so I can accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @JhourladEstrella Oops, typo :) Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the "scope" in the Directive Defn Object

```
ngApp
    .directive('ngCarouselItem', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
              thumbnail: "@",
              title: "@",
              content: "@"
            }
            template: '<div class="item">' +
                      '<div ng-style="background-image: url([[thumbnail]])">' +
                      '<div class="carousel-caption">' +
                      '<h3>[[title]]</h3>' +
                      '<p class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">[[content]]</p>' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '</div>'
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks! It works. I'm giving you an up point. I would have accepted your answer but Omri Ahron has a more comprehensive answer.